# target="_blank"で同一のタブで開きたい。

Tags: html

リンクをクリックするたびに新規タブが増えていくのでなく、はじめの１回目に新規タブが開き、その後は、リンクをクリックしても、同じタブが開かれるようにするにはどうすればいいですか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

常に新しいウィンドウが開かれるのは[`target="_blank"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target)の仕様です。`target="subwindow"`等、`_self`、`_blank`、`_parent`、`_top`以外の名前を付けることで期待通りの動作をするはずです。

Comment: 解決しました！ありがとうございます！